# Why am I getting java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to add a method

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

Good afternoon.
I'm writing a unit test with Mockk in Kotlin.
I need to mock the Android class 'SpannableString'

Here is my code

```
private val spannableString = mockk<SpannableString>()
    @Before
    open fun setup() {
    every { spannableString.toString() } returns SPANNABLE_STRING_VALUE
    every { spannableStringWrapper.get() } returns spannableString
    every { suggestion.id } returns SUGGESTION_ID
    every { suggestion.label } returns "The Shard"
    every { customerSessionStorageProvider.guid } returns "guid"
}
```

So when I run my test class I'm getting:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to add a method

at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:144)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.InlineInstrumentation.doCancel(InlineInstrumentation.kt:60)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.InlineInstrumentation.access$doCancel(InlineInstrumentation.kt:9)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.InlineInstrumentation$execute$cancellation$1.invoke(InlineInstrumentation.kt:20)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.InlineInstrumentation$execute$cancellation$1.invoke(InlineInstrumentation.kt:9)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.transformation.InlineInstrumentation.execute(InlineInstrumentation.kt:43)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.inline(ProxyMaker.kt:88)
at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.ProxyMaker.proxy(ProxyMaker.kt:30)
at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactory.newProxy(JvmMockFactory.kt:34)
at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractMockFactory.newProxy$default(AbstractMockFactory.kt:29)
at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.AbstractMockFactory.mockk(AbstractMockFactory.kt:58)
```

Anyone knows why am I getting that error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you mocking spannable string instead of providing a simple spannable string with SpannableString("foo") ?

Comment: Because I want to later verify the text that the spanable string receives

Comment: And why don't you simple assert that the spannabble has the string that you want?

Comment: you should not be mocking android components/frameworks/code, as android works and it doesn't need testing, instead, you should be testing your own logic and implementation of those frameworks and components